# jQuery Masonry items stacking in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

Hard to describe, but [this codepen](https://codepen.io/alexb148/pen/mdVyEjY) should help make things clear.

With my setup, items are very clearly being stacked in the wrong order.

Most items are 33% width, but I have some 50% width items at the top. I am using a spacer item first, to define the correct size.

For some reason, the 50% items are being stacked on top of each other, when there is very clearly room for them to sit side-by-side. It does this even if I reduce their width to, say 45% - where there is very definitely space for them to sit side-by-side.

It appears to be an actual bug with Masonry, and I have logged an issue with them, but have received no response. Can anyone see why this isn't working? Or provide a fix? Or know of a workaround? Thanks!

For reference, here is the code:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
}

.grid-item--sizer {
  height: 0;
}

.grid-item--width2 {
  width: 240px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Masonry layout is based on a `columnWidth` parameter, and all the grid elements are supposed to have a width that is a multiple of `columnWidth`. In your case, that would mean having 80px base columns.

Remove your sizer element (it's not going to be needed), and change your masonry call to:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 80
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of the columns as having to be multiples of a common base value - that does make sense!
In practice my columns are responsive rather than a fixed width, but if I just half the width of my sizer element that also achieves the same thing - thanks very much!